# flutter web freezes on iphone ios, but not on ipad ios when hosted on firebase. Flutter bug? firebase hosting bug? ios bug?

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, firebase-hosting, flutter-web

I've been working on a flutter web app recently using firebase hosting, and it was working fine until last night. Specifically, the site loads but the interface does not react to user input only on iphone iOS. (i.e. it works properly on ios ipad)

I tried a variety of things to figure out where the problem lies:

- downgraded flutter channel master -> dev + stable (currently using
  dev, but first noticed on master)
- created numerous projects on firebase to host these site.
- reinstalled firebase-tool CLI
- tested on a variety of devices

The easiest way I could recreate this is by creating the following website using the default app created by "flutter create", then performing firebase init, creating a project and then deploying the site.  Here it is: 
[hostingweirdness.firebaseapp.com](https://hostingweirdness.firebaseeapp.com)
also
[hostingweirdness.web.app](http://hostingweirdness.web.app)

What I'm seeing is that the site works perfectly for:

- desktop browsers (chrome,firefox)
- android browsers (chrome),
- ipad safari

However, the blue "+" button is unresponsive for:

- iphone (safari and chrome)
- ipad chrome.

I'd also like to note that I'm able to see the same thing using the iphone simulator for Xcode: works for iphone, not for ipad.

Could you test those sites with your devices and see if you're getting the same thing? 
Any ideas what it might be, or other ideas for troubleshooting?
Any ideas who I can contact to submit a bug report? I'm leaning towards a flutter issue since it's in beta, but changing the channel made no difference, and the fact that it happened all of a sudden makes me think that there could be other culprits.

Comment: it works on ipad chrome and safari

Comment: What ipad? (mine is ipad pro 2016. Only Safari works on that one.)

Comment: A1822 ipad 7th generation 2017 https://imgur.com/Gqfuokp ios 13.3.1

Comment: just right now checked on my iPhone XS Max ...Fab button is not clickable (chrome and safari), weird

Comment: I think I'll submit it to flutter, even though I don't know if it's really their issue. thanks!

Comment: ok.  I submitted it here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was, indeed, a bug.  It's been addressed as of April 13th per this issue here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54269

and they merged the code into flutter here:
https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/17595